# How to manage 100 different main files?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, build-process

Short version of my question:

Is there a way to set up a visual studio solution to build 100 different main files all contained in a single code base, and in a single Visual Studio project?

Long version of my question:

I work with a legacy corporate signal processing library.

The functions in it are clean, well written, highly optimized, and all in ANSI C. (Yes, I know some of those attributes are contradictory)  We have a VS project to build the library, and to publish it to other projects/groups in the company using our corporate code publishing system.

Each "big" library entry point has it's own source file.  Each of these "big" entry points has a thin main wrapper function defined in this file, with a

```
#ifdef FOOMAIN
/* Main for function foo */
main() 
{  
}
#endif
```

I have just learned that these "little" apps are also used by many people around the company.  So, we would like to include these apps in our publishing process.  (At present they are published via a manual back door means.)  We are using VS solutions, and I am curious if we can do this there?

Comment: I'd force everyone to learn python or octave and change those `main()`s to wrappers to them.

Comment: The short answer to your question is: No.

Comment: @erol yeniaras: Couldn't the OP just create a solution with 100 different projects that all build their own exe? Each project would be able to handle its own main entry, it would just be a PITA.

Comment: @Ian : The short question was: "Is there a way to set up a visual studio solution to build 100 different main files all contained in a single code base, and in a single Visual Studio project?" So John wants not only a single solution but also a "single project" having multiple "main"s.

Comment: I'm wondering if instead of 100 "little" programs, each of which link and call a "main-like" entry point in the larger library, it would be best to build a single "little" application that links to the aforementioned library and allows the application user to select the functionality to invoke via command line switch or a configuration file.

Comment: @Blukes this is an interesting point.  One example of exactly this approach would be git.  I was hoping to avoid having to modify 100 different files to do this....  That said, a judicious awk/sed script could automate all that....  I think you should write that up as an answer.